# Customize GWT Checkbox with * mark when its checked

Tags: gwt

want to customize the gwt checkbox with * mark when its checked, could you please help me out here. thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo code

1. Create checkbox instance
2. Add clickHandler to instance
3. On click check selection status. Update text by checkBoxInstance.setText()